# Querying Database with SQLAlchemy, returning the object only

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy

I am working with flask and SQLalchemy, everything is coming together, but when I want to query the database to return data, it is simply returning the object, and not the information, for example the column info, inside the object.

Class

```
class stock_info(db.Model):
    #information in here#
```

When Querying Database

```
            myStock = stock_info.query.get(6)
            print("This is the info: ", myStock)
```

Output

```
<stock_info 6>
```

It is returning the correct data, but it is just showing me the object, how can I return what is inside eg the column data and then I am parsing the info after that etc.,

Do I need to put it into a dataframe or like select which column I would like to see?

Comment: Do you want to access the data within the object, or fetch the raw data without the object?

Comment: I want to access the data within the object, for example what I am trying to do is get everything from the first column '"stock_name", I am trying to see if the stock is already there so I do not need to spend money on an API call to IEXfinance, and I can just query the database and then use the data that is already saved, for use in my algorithm, that is what I am going for here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mystock` is the object and which has the info you need.

For accessing a specific column from `mystock` object, you can do it this way

```
mystock.stock_name
```

which would return the value of stock_name column of the selected row.

You can furthur read the [docs](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/queries/#querying-records)

Comment: Wow, literally was that all I was missing? I feel so dumb, thank you, sorry I am new to working with databases but I should have figured that.